# Can you some how add a class to a </div> tag specify what div ends there?

Tags: html

Like if I had:

```
<div class="body">

<div class="logo">
<img...>
</div>

<p>some text</p>
</div>
```

Could I go...

```
<div class="body">

<div class="logo">
<img...>
</div class="logo">

<p>some text</p>
</div>
```

...so that it knows to end the second div and not the first?(this is a light example of what I am trying to do, but I think you get it)

(and if it is possible, a way using just HTML or css)

Comment: You need to learn how to indent your code properly and than you wont look for such unstandardised ways to maintain your html.

Comment: Closing tags (ie. `</div>`) can never have attributes - at best the attributes will be ignored. Closing tags are also always .. closing a tag that has been previously opened, and they must be correctly paired in a "tree" hierarchy. There are 'odd browser differences' that can occur if the HTML is malformed. The [W3 has an HTML Validator](https://validator.w3.org/) which can answer these sorts of questions.

Answer (score 3):

If your motive is to identify the closing tag effectively means, possibly you can use the comments

```
<div class="body">

<div class="logo">
<img...>
</div> <!-- logo div closed here -->

<p>some text</p>
</div>
```

Proper formatted code will help to find the closing tag hierarchy.

Comment: I mean like so that the browser will know of all my </div> tags, what <div> goes with what </div>, if that makes sense.

Comment: html parser in browser will parse the code
https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#html-parser

Comment: You put the source link in the answer itself, not in the comments. There isn't much of a point in having "(source)" in the answer if it's not even going to point anywhere. And you use blockquotes, not code blocks, for quotations. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing and try again.

Comment: @PG55: The browser will know, you don't have to worry about that so long as you make sure your tags are nested correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can, but great news coming: you don't need to!
The moment you put a `</div>`, than the closest (going backwards) `div` (and therefore its class/classes) will close.

Indentation helps understanding how it works:

```
<div class="first">
  <div class="second">
    <div class="third"> <!-- Next closing div closes "third" -->
    </div> <!-- Next closing div closes "second" -->
  </div> <!-- Next closing div closes "first" -->
</div>
```

Another example:

```
<div class="first">
  <div class="second"> <!-- Next closing div closes closest one, in this case "second" -->
  </div>
  <div class="third"> <!-- Next closing div closes "third" -->
 </div> <!-- Next closing div closes "first" -->
</div>
```

Notes:

> - You might want to look into learning how to style element's children, like all the `<p>` elements in all `<div>` elements which have the `class="cool"`.
>     This could avoid the need to close and reopen the same classes multiple times.
> - This game teaches child selection in a **great and visual way**: http://flukeout.github.io
> - Lastly, note that there **currently is no parent selector in CSS**.   What that is (Er.. *would be*) you'll figure out yourself soon after learning about child selection.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.

Closing tags always close the most recently opened matching tag. In your example, it simply works as desired. And the alternative would not be valid markup: tags cannot overlap.